# draw simple line chart with google chart json data with dates on x axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have taken a look at the other answers at SO, but none caters to my need. 
Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline#Example) which tells how to plot dates on charts. Following is one of the sample json objects:

```
datetime: "2012-07-07"
hours: "0.6"
shop: "WalMart"
name: "Andrew"
__proto__: Object
```

I use the following code to add rows and columns:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Hours');  
  $.each(hour_logs, function(key, value){// hour_logs is the collection of json objects, the sample is shown above.
    ymd = value.datetime.split("-");
    var dt = new Date(parseInt(ymd[0]), parseInt(ymd[1]), parseInt(ymd[2]));         
    data.addRow(dt, parseInt(value.hours));
  }); 
  console.log(data);
  var options = {
    title: 'Daily Logs',
    displayAnnotations: true,  
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

**But i get an error, uncaught Error: Not an array. How to fix it.**

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing an array when adding a row.

Should be:

```
data.addRow([dt, parseInt(value.hours)]);
```

instead of:

```
data.addRow(dt, parseInt(value.hours));
```

Comment: Well, you are using `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable` to provide data to the chart, which expects an array of arrays (have a look to this example: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#line_chart). 
In your example, you are adding rows (one by one using `addRow`, don't get confused with `addRows`) so you may use `google.visualization.DataTable();`
Hope this helps.